# count lines of changed between two branches in SourceTree

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been trying to see if we have any command which can give me lines of changed in sourcetree between two branches.

command - git diff --stat branch1..branch2 -- '*.cs'

It gives me file changed along with Insert & Delete lines. As any modified entry soourcetree treat as deletion and insertion so the above command doesn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.